# Vectorize the operation on two vectors to produce a matrix

Tags: matrix, vector

"""

I have two vectors A and B of integers. I need to build a matrix X of (rows, columns)=(len(B), len(A)) based on these two vectors in the following way:
for any pair of integers (i, j) (i<rows and j<columns), if A[i] ==B[j], then X[j][i] =1, else X[j][i] =1. The following code works:

"""

```
import numpy as np

A=np.array([3,6,12,14])

B=np.array([1,12,14,23,33])

X=np.zeros((len(B),len(A))) 

for i in range(len(A)):

    for j in range(len(B)):

        if A[i]==B[j]:

            X[j][i]=1
```

"""

I would like to vectorize the operation as I have two huge vectors. I appreciate your help. Thank you very much.

"""

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [list comprehension](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp):

```py
X = [[1 if i == j else 0 for i in a] for j in b]
```

This solution iterates over `a` and `b` directly, which is preferred in python. `i` is an element in `a`, and `j` is an element in `b`. It also does not use numpy, but the list can be converted to a numpy array.

EDIT: Here is a partially vectorized solution using [np.where](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html).

```py
x = np.array([np.where(x == a, 1, 0) for x in b])
```

Comment: Thank you Ealker. Yes, list comprehension works and can speed up about 20%. But I would still like to see how to vectorize it.

Comment: @user11809571 I updated my answer with a partially vectorized solution. I don't think it can be fully vectorized, since vectorization by it's nature should only work by doing a single action across a 1D buffer. I'm no expert in vectorization though so I could be wrong.

Comment: Thank you very much Ealker.  I still need to time it to compare with the result obtained using list comprehension. The problem is that this toy problem is not my real question. I have made changes to the original post to reflect my real question. It can't seem to be answered based on your solution.  I wonder whether you can help with that, too. Thank you.

Comment: I'll start a new post, sorry.